# The fastest way to convert between enum and Int in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I want to convert an enum into Int or vice verse, i.e. implement an bidirectional mapping between the tag of sum type and Int. I have tried `fromEnum` but it seems not fast enough, and then I tried `unsafeCoerce` but it doesn't works as expected:

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Int
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)

data Color = R | G | B
    deriving (Enum)

main = do
    printT 1 $ (unsafeCoerce R :: Int8)
    printT 1000 $ (unsafeCoerce G :: Int8)
    printT 1000000 $ (unsafeCoerce B :: Int8)
    printT 1000000000 $ (unsafeCoerce R :: Int8)

    printT 1 $ (fromEnum R)
    printT 1000 $ (fromEnum G)
    printT 1000000 $ (fromEnum B)
    printT 1000000000 $ (fromEnum B)

---------- profile tools ------------

printT :: Show a => Int -> a -> IO ()
printT n x = print =<< timeIt n (pure x)

timeIt :: Int -> IO a -> IO a
timeIt n _ | n <= 0 = error "timeIt n | n <= 0"
timeIt n proc = do
    t0 <- getCurrentTime
    replicateM_ (n-1) proc
    x <- proc
    t1 <- getCurrentTime
    putStrLn ("-- Time Used (repeat " ++ show n ++ " times): " ++ show (t1 `diffUTCTime` t0))
    return x
```

So what is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: What is "*not fast enough*". I would be supprised if this is really a bottleneck.

Comment: I am not convinced you here run banchmarks on `fromEnum`. At first sight you run benchmarks on the `pure` itself, at first sight `fromEnum R`, etc. are never evaluated. Likely `unsafeCoerce R` and `fromEnum R` will produce (approximately) the same results, since we never really make the evaluation.

Comment: Note: When profiling times in Haskell, the easiest method to do so is usually by using [criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/). I recommend using this library to ensure that your benchmarks are as accurate as possible.

Comment: Note that `unsafeCoerce` is 100% incorrect here and liable to crash your program at surprising times. GHC does not represent `Int8` and a 3-constructor sum type in anything resembling the same memory layout.

Comment: Derived `toEnum` and `fromEnum` are really, really fast. They are, in fact, the fastest way the GHC developers have found to "convert an enum into `Int` or vice [versa], i.e. implement an bidirectional mapping between the tag of sum type and `Int`." In the event that you find a faster way, you should submit a merge request to GHC; the performance of this code has always been a pretty high priority.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `Enum` you actually care about your type, or someone else's? If it's someone else's, then you're not guaranteed any methods you can use besides `fromEnum`, so you're out of luck. If it's your own type, then you can reimplement it with a `newtype` and pattern synonyms instead of deriving, so that `fromEnum` is literally free (provided the compiler can specialize it wherever you use it):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

module ColorEnum (Color(R,G,B)) where

import Data.Coerce (coerce)

newtype Color = UnsafeColor Int

pattern R, G, B :: Color
pattern R = UnsafeColor 0
pattern G = UnsafeColor 1
pattern B = UnsafeColor 2

maxColor :: Int
maxColor = 2

instance Enum Color where
  succ (UnsafeColor a)
    | a == maxColor = error "succ{Color}: tried to take `succ' of last tag in enumeration"
    | otherwise = UnsafeColor (a + 1)
  pred (UnsafeColor a)
    | a == 0 = error "pred{Color}: tried to take `pred' of first tag in enumeration"
    | otherwise = UnsafeColor (a - 1)
  toEnum a
    | a >= 0 && a <= maxColor = UnsafeColor a
    | otherwise = error $ "toEnum{Color}: tag (" ++ show a ++ ") is outside of enumeration's range (0," ++ show maxColor ++ ")"
  enumFrom (UnsafeColor a) = coerce [a..maxColor]
  enumFromThen (UnsafeColor a) (UnsafeColor b) = coerce [a,b..if a > b then 0 else maxColor]
  fromEnum = coerce
```

Caveats:

- This is not an endorsement of how you did your benchmark (in fact, it probably is wrong, as commenters pointed out)
- There's a good chance that things other than `fromEnum` will be made slower by this change
- All of that code is just to replace `data Color = R | G | B deriving (Enum)`

Comment: `toEnum a | (fromIntegral a :: Word) <= fromIntegral maxColor = ...` is likely better using the native code generator. I imagine LLVM will do that automatically.